# Grouping & Aggregation about Character linking [in SQL HANA DATABASE]

Tags: r, plyr, hana

My data frame like this:

```
> mydata
   time  id  product
1 201301  1   apple
2 201302  1     htc
3 201302  1   apple
4 201302  2     htc
5 201302  2   apple
```

How get the following result?

```
> result
   time   id   product
1 201301  1     apple
2 201302  1 apple&htc
3 201302  2 apple&htc
```

I have tried `ddply()`function like this:

```
ddply(mydata,.(time,id),summarise,paste0(product,"&",product))
```

But it doesn't work as my expectation.Thanks for your answers.

***And, my point is, how to realize in SQL in SAP HANA DATABASE? Thanks a lot!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 ddply(tab, .(time, id), summarise, product = paste(product, collapse="&"))
```

hth

Comment: sorry i can't help you with data base